# can boost have maps with integer keys?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I have boost map with the definition as below:

```
typedef std::pair< int,complex_data > map_value_type;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<map_value_typemanaged_shared_memory::segment_manager> map_value_type_allocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::map<  int, complex_data, std::less<  int>,map_value_type_allocator > complex_map_type;
```

I took the code from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers_of_containers and replaced the keys with integers. However I am getting the following error i can not resolve:

`/usr/include/boost/container/map.hpp:147:1: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’`

If I replace the keys the code seems to work fine. Can anyone see what the problem is here?

Comment: Is your real code also missing a `,` from the definition of `map_value_type_allocator`?

Comment: It is a static assertion that is triggered, have you bothered looking at the code/error message on what is actually asserted?

Comment: If I simply "replace the keys with integers", then it compiles without error: http://ideone.com/XkhLp (although that gives link errors due to libraries not being available at ideone). Could you post your code so we can see where it's gone wrong?

Comment: Please post a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: using the example in the above i have managed to reverse engineer and resolve the problem - is it possible to have an unsigned int as the key?

Comment: @godzilla: You can use any type as the key, as long as two values can be compared using either `<` or a custom comparator. Certainly, any integer type is fine.

Comment: thanks god it working, it turns out the key must be a const!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is familiar to those with experience in C++ template programming. Ignore the `sizeof` part; the clue is in `boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>`. That type shouldn't be instantiated, you want `boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<true>`. But what exact expression is used as the template argument?

Your template instantiation error should have an instantiation stack, which leads from your code to the failure. Presumably it's checking